# Angular: Dynamically Changing Click Events and Handlers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, event-handling, dom-events

I have a component that will have a set of states, in which each state has a set of UI events and response methods. Some of the UI events may not be included in all the states.

My current idea is to create a controller interface including methods for each possible UI event that the component can then call in response to each event. Each state will then have a corresponding implementation of the interface. The main issue here is that many of the concrete controllers will have empty methods being called.

To avoid this issue, the only solution I can think of is to not even use Angular directives and have each concrete controller create its own event listeners. While this would avoid the previous issue, I am wondering whether there's a better approach relying on Angular features.

Comment: It sounds like your component is doing too much. Is it possible to break it into a component per state?

Comment: @DM I don't think so because each state corresponds to the same DOM element. To give more context, it will be an SVG editor that will have different modes (draw, erase, drag, etc.). This component corresponds to the SVG display.